# remove spaces and carriage returns from Plone content with Diazo(minimizing html code)

Tags: plone, strip, diazo

I have a Plone site, themed with plone.app.theming.

how diazo minimizing html content?
and remove spaces and carriage returns

Content:

```
    <html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>



<div id="content">
<p>Not empty paragraph text</p>


<p><span>Not empty paragraph element</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    </head><body><div id="content"><p>Not empty paragraph text</p><p><span>Not empty paragraph element</span></div></body></html>
```

Comment: This is XSLT processing level thing. Most likely the answer is "you can do it in some very complex way, but it just adds CPU overhead and there is very little gain".

Comment: Pick the right tool for the right purpose. XSLT is a clumsy minimizing tool. Instead, turn on gzip compression in your reverse proxy or with the Plone caching settings.

Comment: You can't reliably -- you don't know which whitespace is relevant to the output without consulting the corresponding CSS.

Comment: Is it possible you're asking how to *stop* diazo/xslt from removing white space?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove leading and trailing whitespace and replace sequences of whitespace characters by a single space with `normalize-space` as follows:

```xml
<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:template>
```

We use it together with the following:

```xml
<xsl:template match="comment()"/>
<xsl:template match="node()[@style='display:none']"/>
```

This might help you minimizing some of your html-code.

Removing CR and Tabs will require a more complex set of rules.