# How to stop Diazo from stripping whitespace in Plone?

Tags: plone, diazo

Plone 4.1.7
plone.app.theming 1.0

I found this question which is similar to my question except this person wants to do the opposite: [remove spaces and carriage returns from Plone content with Diazo(minimizing html code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532919/remove-spaces-and-carriage-returns-from-plone-content-with-diazominimizing-html)

I want Diazo to stop stripping out whitespace, as it's stripping out a lot of it that is needed for formatting. This seems to be the case even if my rules.xml is empty - just enabling a theme seems to do it, rather than it being an aspect of a particular theme.

Turning the theme on/off also causes a bug on only one particular page (a view named '@@upload') where all of the classes in the <body> tag are stripped out. Unsure if that is at all related, although I do know it's Diazo causing it.

Edit: Some further info: I don't have the non-themed side blocked by host name in the control panel, but rather by use of the <notheme> tag in rules.xml. I have to do this because the non-themed side is on the same domain as the themed side.

Comment: I've never heard of it and never hand any problem with it. Maybe this issue is not related to diazo? Maybe something with plones html filtering?

Comment: I can confirm that toggling "enable theme" on/off will alter this behavior, so to that extent I know diazo is involved. But something lower level may to be blame, like lxml